# Javascript substrings multiline replace by RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having some troubles with matching a regular expression in multi-line string.

```
<script>
var str="Welcome to Google!\n";
str = str + "We are proud to announce that Microsoft has \n";
str = str + "one of the worst Web Developers sites in the world.";

document.write(str.replace(/.*(microsoft).*/gmi, "$1"));
</script>
```

http://jsbin.com/osoli3/3/edit

As you may see on the link above, the output of the code looks like this:

```
Welcome to Google! Microsoft one of the worst Web Developers sites in the world.
```

Which means, that the replace() method goes line by line and if there's no match in that line, it returns just the whole line... **Even if it has the "m" (multiline) modifier**...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiline option only changes how the codes `^` and `$` work, not how the code `.` works.

Use a pattern where you match any character using a set like `[\w\W]` instead of `.`, as that only matches non-linebreak characters.

```
document.write(str.replace(/[\w\W]*(microsoft)[\w\W]*/gmi, "$1"));
```